# Probability some slot more than one object

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I place $\sqrt[10]{n^{9}}$ objects into $n$ slots  at random, uniformly (note: $n^{0.9}$ will be guaranteed to be an integer).  What's the probability that some slot gets at least $2$ objects? What about the same situation, but now $3$ objects?

---

To approach this problem, I sorta just plugged in values for $n$.

When $n = 1,$ obviously $p = 0$.

When $n = 138414549$,  we put $111111111$ balls into $138414549$ boxes at random. The probability that every ball is put into a unique box is given by

$$\left(1 - \frac{1}{1111111111}\right)\left(1 - \frac{1}{1111111111 - 1}\right) \cdots \left(1 - \frac{1}{1111111111 - 138414549}\right) $$

So, I think the answer is just

$$\left(1 - \frac{1}{n} \right)\left(1 - \frac{1}{n - 1}\right)\left(1 - \frac{1}{n - 2}\right) \cdots \left(1 - \frac{1}{n - n^{0.9}}\right)$$

for the first part of the question. Now what about the probability of getting three objects in one slot?

My questions are

1) Is my calculation to the first part correct?

2) How can I approach the second part?

Comment: you mean n^(10/9) is an integer?

Comment: I had made a typo. see the edit please